# Vim map command to save file and run a test

Tags: vim

How could I map a command to save the current file and then run it?

I am trying this:

```
:nnoremap <leader>r :w<CR>| !python %
```

This runs the python command instantly but not when I call the leader key. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to follow up on what Conner was saying, you can do something like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>r :w \| !python %<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I don't need the pipe character when writing a map, just a second colon:

```
:nnoremap <leader>r :w<CR> :!python % <CR>
```

Comment: You can use the pipe if you leave out the `<CR>`

Comment: Also note that the right hand side of a mapping (here, it's `:w<CR> :!python % <CR>`) is a sequence of keystrokes to be executed. So here, after doing `:w<CR>`, your mapping would make you press the spacebar, which probably isn't what you want.